# Add and remove input of Angular form according to yes/no radio-button selection

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I am trying to add/remove an input from an Angular form according to a yes/no radio-button selection.

At the moment I have made that with an ngIf directive but when I see, the property remains in the JSON object of the form, and the form continuous to remain invalid.

Please provide any suggestion to remove the input definitely when the no option is selected or propose me a better way to do this.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/jreategui07/form-test

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Add and Remove the control from the form based on the radio value change

```
//Add:
this.formTest.addControl('phoneNumber',['', Validators.required]);

//Remove:
this.formTest.removeControl('phoneNumber');
```

Angular FormGroup: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

**Update:**

```
this.formTest.addControl('phoneNumber',new FormControl('',[Validators.required]));
```

Comment: Hi, I am having an error trying this: this.formTest.addControl('phoneNumber', ['', Validators.required]);

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy follow below code:->

```
 <input name="options"  [(ngModel)]="options" type="radio" [value]="true" [checked]="options"/> Yes

 <input name="options"[(ngModel)]="options" type="radio" [value]="false" [checked]="!options"/> No

 <div *ngIf="options">
<input name="displaying input if its true">
</div>
 <div *ngIf="!options">
<input name="displaying input if its false"> // In your case don't display input.
</div>
```